# Are Zonal Statistics possible in PostGIS2?

Tags: open-source-gis, spatial-statistics, postgis-2.0

Now with postgis2 which supports rasters by default is it possible to do a zonal statistics analysis?

I've google it but I haven't found anything solid? Is there a tutorial outthere to get me started?

Can anyone give me an sql example on how to do it?

**EDIT :**

**An updated (simplified) query according the [blog](http://movingspatial.blogspot.gr/2012/07/postgis-20-intersect-raster-and-polygon.html) Aragon mention :**

```
CREATE TABLE sum_pop3 AS 
 SELECT gid, SUM((ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(rast,1,geom))).sum)
 FROM perez_grid, ls_den
 WHERE ST_Intersects(geom,rast) 
GROUP BY gid;
```

Comment: Hi @nickves, did you ever manage to get zonal stats working? I can't seem to get the updated query working.

Comment: @CliffPatterson  remember I did work out - it's been three years since then, a lot have changed. I am going try out the querry later and confirm or update.

Comment: something must have changed from the last time I used that; not enough time at the moment to see where the Query kicks. if you manage to fix it please free to update

Comment: Check out my recent [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172772/zonal-statistics-of-polygon-overlays-in-postgis) on the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should check out **Store, manipulate and analyze raster data within 
the PostgreSQL/PostGIS spatial database** document by Pierre Racine and Steve Cumming which was presented at FOSS, [here](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/raw-attachment/wiki/WKTRaster/PierreRacine_FOSS4G-2011.pdf&ei=1OJrUMXoEI-Shgfjs4DIDg&usg=AFQjCNHWWPFinWBhqFdfy9KKz9AKuGCASg&cad=rja). There are lots of function defined as raster statistics to solve your problem. i think ST_SummaryStats will help you about zonal statics, of course, not enough.

> `ST_SummaryStats(raster)` will turn you a set of (min, max, sum, mean,
>   stddev, count (of withdata pixels)) records.

Postgis 2.0 supports zonal statistics analysis with some sql queries which you have work on. i have came across a good documentation on net about zonal statitics with esri vs postgis 2.0. you should check out for some information at Moving Spatial [here](http://movingspatial.blogspot.com/2012/07/postgis-20-intersect-raster-and-polygon.html). both of them was given the same statistics result with some hard querying.

example query which was taken from Anthony Lopez site i have mentioned before...

```
 CREATE TABLE sum_pop2 AS
WITH 
   feat AS (SELECT gid, geom FROM perez_grid AS b ),
   b_stats AS
(SELECT  gid, (stats).*
FROM (
SELECT gid, ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(rast,1,geom)) AS stats
FROM ls_den
INNER JOIN feat
ON ST_Intersects(feat.geom,rast) ) AS foo )
SELECT gid, SUM(count) AS cell_count
  ,SUM(sum) AS population
FROM b_stats
 WHERE count > 0
GROUP BY gid
ORDER BY gid;
```

> Esri Zonal Statistics result: 
>   Population: 207,578 
>   Cell Count: 14,400
>
> Postgis Method result:
>   Population: 207,578
>   Cell Count: 14,400
>   .
>
> Population Percent Difference: 0%

i havent tried it yet but Anthony mentioned that there was some performance problem with raster analysis with postgis.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: It is a good starting point!